# Restore mysql db from AWS AMI?

Tags: mysql, aws, amazon-ec2, postgresql, phpmyadmin

We have one EC2 instance running our mysql database server.

due to a security incident we had to delete the current EC2 instance as database was completely messed up with some sort of encryption.

So we had to recover it from Snapshot/AMI that are being taken every 6 hours. we have past 1 months snapshots and AMI's available for this EC2 instance.

This EC2 instance has only one SSD (Persistent Block Storage) EBS volume, which is part of the Snapshots/AMI's.

We also have phpmyadmin installed but its not able to connect to DB for obvious reasons!

Below are the details of OS and the mysql Service status.

**# cat /etc/*release***

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

**# mysqld --version**

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

**# systemctl status mysql.service**

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Mon 2021-03-01 13:19:50 UTC; 241ms ago
    Process: 79728 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 79736 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1164)
     Memory: 91.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─79736 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Mar 01 13:19:50 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Mar 01 13:19:52 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 01 13:19:52 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 01 13:19:52 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Mar 01 13:19:53 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 328.
Mar 01 13:19:53 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Mar 01 13:19:53 ip-172-31-93-250 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

**# journalctl -xe**

```
Mar 01 13:14:20 ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 01 13:14:20 ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 01 13:14:20 ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 105083 and the job result is failed.
Mar 01 13:14:21 ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 206.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Mar 01 13:14:21 ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 105149 and the job result is done.
Mar 01 13:14:21 ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 105149.
```

For additional Log output of [**"# tail -500 /var/log/mysql/error.log"**](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pc5jHyZdJX/)

Can any of you please help me restore the mysql service with the data/databases?

We are not sure what is the right procedure to follow in this scenario to restore the databases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have lots of errors stating: "Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address" which means that something else is already running on the IP and port you are binding MySQL to.  This would normally happen if you already have a MySQL process running on the requested IP and port.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue the only thing you have to do is below:

just edit **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** file using whichever editor you like and update the bind address using whichever editor you like. below is the line you need to update with the correct/updated IP address. because when you launch a new EC2 instance using an backup AMI image or Snapshot it gets a new private IP Address (Unless you have made it static in your OS configuration earlier.)

**bind-address           = 192.168.XXX.XXX**

Then restart the mysql service using below command and everything will start working as earlier including the PHP My Admin console.

**systemctl restart mysql.service**